# predict function gives opposite predictions than expected by the model used

Tags: r, predictive-models, lme4-nlme

I want to use a model fitted on a [simulation dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8ggt9stwsajbos/example.csv?dl=0) to predict the outcomes in a new, real [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2k1rmvmyrpwi6z/realdata.csv?dl=0). Basically, I try to predict attack outcomes (coded as "escape"or "body") based on the speed, body length (SVL), tail length, tail color contrast and escape strategy. Because the simulation dataset comes from repeated game sessions from different players, I entered player as random factor. Thus, I fit a generalized mixed model under a logit link function (see example below).

The fitted model tells me speed is the most important factor and decreases the odds of being hit in the body, tail size is the second most powerful term and it increases the odds of hits in the body (oddly enough) but with less intensity, body length (svl) also increases the odds of hits on the body and finally, strategy (running, compared to burrowing) decreases the odds of hitting the body with less intensity thantil size but greater than svl.

All good, the problem comes when I try to apply this model to a new data set. In the new dataset, individuals of type A are slower and elongated but the model predicts they will have lower odds of being hit on the body. Despite these individuals burrow instead of run and have shorter tails, the effects sizes of both terms should not be more important than the fact that they are slower and have long bodies. Thus, I am left with the uncomfortable feeling that predict is not working OK here.

Any help is more than welcome.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
 results=read.csv("gameresults.csv")
 results[,c("speed","svl","reltailsize","tailsize","tailcontrst")]=colwise(scale,center=F)(results[,c("speed","svl","reltailsize","tailsize","tailcontrst")])

 #results[,c("speed","svl","tailsize","tailcontrst")]=colwise(function(x){return(x/max(x))})(results[,c("speed","svl","tailsize","tailcontrst")])
 results$result=relevel(results$result, ref="escape")
 require(lme4)
 colnames(results)
 bodyescape=results[results$result%in%c("body","escape"),]
 test=glmer(result~speed+strategy+svl+tailsize+tailcontrst
       +(1|player),data=bodyescape,family=binomial(link = "logit"))

 summary(test)
```

Thus, speed and tail size have the biggest effects. While the former decreases the odds of attacks in the body, the latter does the opposite.

```
  # odds of hits on the tail for real data
   rd=read.csv("realdata.csv")
   rd[,c("speed","svl","tailsize","tailcontrst")]=colwise(scale,center=F)(rd[,c("speed","svl","tailsize","tailcontrst")])
   pred=predict(test, newdata=rd,re.form=NA)
   resd=cbind(rd,pred);resd
  # test effect of type for different predatory outcomes
   M=gls(pred~type,method="REML",data = resd)
   summary(M)# type A has lower odds of hits on the body, despite being slower and more elongated.
```